# Android Programming, C#: Show a certain line of code, only when a certain button is pressed

Tags: android

here is my beginner problem.
Ive just been introduced to android programming, and now im just playing with a simple calculator program, only to see how i connect my xaml files with my source code. all the program does really is ask for two integers, then add them together, and, if the "equals" button is pressed, displays the result in an empty EditText.

1) is an EditText the right empty box to display a result? 
2) how do i get the EditText to display my result when the equal button is pressed? here is the bit of code where im lacking the "if-declaration":

```
 //output result 
        if //button result is clicked: 
            {
            res.Text = res.ToString();
            }
```

can you hint me towards the right if declaration?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. I would suggest using a Textbox
2. If you are using Xamarin for Android. First you have to locate the button

Get a reference to the controls that were created in the layout file via the Android Designer. Then add the following code inside the OnCreate method, after the call to SetContentView

```
Button buttonEqual = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.CallButton);
```

Then add the following code to response to the button click

```
buttonEqual.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    // When the button is clicked,
    // display the result in the textbox
    textBox.Text = res.ToString();
}
```

Comment: hi and thanks! sound cool, the problem is, when i insert this bit into my mainactivity, it underlines the "object" and "eventargs". im pretty new to this, are those place holders? thanks!